# Como guardar dados temporariamente com boas práticas?

Tags: javascript, java, html, session

Tenho somente uma página onde estão todos os scripts, quando um usuário clicasse em certo dado, iria redireciona-lo para um script especifico e  precisei guardar este dado (o qual ele clicou) para poder colocar num  caso ele desejasse editar este dado posteriormente.

Para fazer isso, através de JS peguei o dado, mandei para a API em Java onde guardei como session para depois retornar quando necessário através de um método get, dessa forma para poder colocar como value do  e ele saber qual dado está editando (No get, JS chama a API na qual retorna o dado/session e JS insere no value).

Não sei se essa foi a melhor solução, existem outras? Uma prática melhor? Sem ter que enviar a variável pelo botão via HTML.

Comment: por javascript, pode usar a sessionStorage ou localStorage, se achar mais prático: http://zenorocha.com/html5-local-storage/ (isso elimina qualquer envio de dados do navegador ao servidor)

Comment: @LeonardoBosquett Realmente, muito mais fácil o/

Comment: E no caso para que seja compatível com navegadores antigos?

Comment: navegadores muito antigos provavelmente não terão esse recurso, dê uma olhada aqui (mas veja que até mesmo o IE8 dá suporte ao recurso): http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Comment: Obrigada a todos! Pouparam muitas linhas de código. 
@Lollipop Estranho seria programadorA homem hahaha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na prática? Problema nenhum, se o que você quer é que um usuário anônimo ou não preencha um campo no qual depois de navegar em qualquer outra página e voltar para esta, o campo estará sempre preenchido naquela sessão, a resposta realmente é essa.

Agora uma resposta longa:
A grande restrição que as pessoas geralmente (ou pelo menos na minha experiência) fazem em relação a guardar dados na `SESSION` é em relação ao tamanho da informação que você está armazenando, ou seja, se esta informação não é tão grande não tem problema nenhum em fazer isso. Agora o que seria uma informação grande? Bom, no caso da Session depende muito da capacidade do seu Servidor, recomendação minha, nada que ultrapasse os 100kb de armazenamento, peguemos como exemplo os Cookies que  tem limite de 20 kb mas que por outro lado são enviados e recebidos a cada requisição, logo a `SESSION` pode ser um pouco maior.

A grande questão em quando escolher o tipo de forma de armazenamento a se adotar é fazer-se perguntas como:

- A informação à armazenar é grande?
- A informação é temporária ou algo que deverá ser salvo por um longo período?
- A informação é confidencial?

Com essas perguntas acredito que podemos chegar a conclusões, por exemplo:
 - Se não for tão grande (100kb), temporária e confidencial, posso salvar na sessão
 - Se for pequena (2kb, 5kb), temporária e não confidencial, posso salvar nos cookies
 - Se for grande devo salvar num banco ou arquivo(daqui já seria necessária uma identificação do usuário de alguma forma).

Fique claro que, não estou impondo regras, tenha em mente que regras são muito importantes mas nada é melhor do que o bom senso, cada situação tem sua melhor alternativa mesmo que quebre padrões, como grandes escritores já disseram: regras foram feitas para serem quebradas.